# radiobuttons - test if checked - why do first 2 approaches fail?

Tags: c#, radio-button

I was wondering why below did not work as expected... 
if if-statement changed to (!ctrl.checked) it returns all radio-button's names)

myForm f = new myForm();

```
        foreach (RadioButton ctrl in f.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
        {
            if (ctrl.Checked)
                MessageBox.Show(ctrl.Name);
        }
```

I also tried

```
        foreach (Control c in f.controls)
            if (c is radiobutton)
            {
                if (c.Checked)
                {
                    messagebox.show(c.name);
                }
```

when I then put all radio-buttons in a group-box and used below code:

```
        foreach (RadioButton c in groupBox1.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(c.Name);
            }
        }
```

it worked fine.

what's the difference here.

any help appreciated

Comment: Based on the first line of example code, it looks like you just newed up a form and then looked at the `Checked` property. Are any radio buttons actually defaulted to `true` for `Checked`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your radio button is the child of a control other than the form.  You need to recursively search for the radio buttons.

```
    public void DisplayRadioButtons()
    {
        Form f = new Form();
        RecursivelyFindRadioButtons(f);
    }

    private static void RecursivelyFindRadioButtons(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
        {
            RecursivelyFindRadioButtons(childControl);
            if (childControl is RadioButton && ((RadioButton) childControl).Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(childControl.Name);
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I set one radio button to default checked and it was correctly detected as checked as suggested by TyCobb, does not work though if I check a different button. Do you know what I am missing. This works in Vb/VBA, just started with c#...

Comment: The workflow you're describing isn't quite clear...  When do you check a different button?  When do you want the message to appear?